import/export class with webpack and babel
I am having this error when import/export JS class, but not with JS function. So I want to seek help here to fix this problem.
I have this folder structure, with the following simple JS code:
 src
 ├── scripts
 │   ├── entries
 │   │   └── main.js
 │   └── lib
 │       └── base.js
 ├── styles
 │   └── main.css
 ├── package.json
 ├── babel.config.json
 └── webpack.config.json

In main.js:
import Base from "../lib/base"
new Base()

In base.js:
class Base {
  constructor () {}
}

export default Base

In babel.config.json:
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {}
    ]
  ]
}

In webpack.config.json:
const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname)
const ASSETS_DIR = path.join(ROOT, 'assets')
const SRC_DIR = path.join(ROOT, 'src')
const SCRIPT_ENTRIES_DIR = path.join(SCRIPTS_DIR, 'entries')
const VENDORS_DIR = path.join(ROOT, 'node_modules')

export default env => {
  return {
    entry: {
      'entry-main': path.resolve(SCRIPT_ENTRIES_DIR, 'main.js')
    },
    output: {
      filename: `[name].js?v=${Date.now()}`,
      path: ASSETS_DIR
    },
    ...

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: VENDORS_DIR,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  }
}

In package.json:
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "webpack --env production --progress --color",
    ...
  },
  ...
}

So when I run npm run build in command line, there is this error:
ERROR in ./src/scripts/lib/base.js 1:0-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.symbol.js' in '~/src/scripts/lib'
 @ ./src/scripts/entries/main.js 1:0-28


But when I change base.js into a function, running npm run build will work fine:
const B = function () {}

export default B

Is there any ways for me to export/import class instead of function, since I need it to be base class and the other classes could extend from it.

Please provide the package.json so we can see the package versions.
